# Issues with Scheduling and Outlook Email / Outlook App / Integrated Mail on iOS?

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office, calendar, ical

I have the following installed on my systems:

- Windows

  - Outlook
- iOS

  - Integrated Calendar / Mail
  - Integrated Outlook Mail

A meeting was scheduled to do an  test install and rollback of a system, and the alarm went off for it, but when I asked my boss about it, he said it was rescheduled to another time.

I don't understand what happened.  Shouldn't the meeting have been moved to another time on the calendar if they rescheduled it?  The Integrated Calendar had the alarm for it go off, the Outlook app did not...and the Windows desktop application also had notification.

I can't uninstall the integrated calendar or email on iOS, and my thought is that  this is what has this paired down, how do I deal with meetings that other people (I'm assuming) put on the calendar and forget to remove when they reschedule them, if they have different names from what they rescheduled the meeting to?

Comment: You didn’t say what email systems/services you are using.  Can you lease add these details?

Comment: @Allan Exchange O365 I believe...

Comment: Confirm that everything in *Accounts* is configured as “Exchange”